# Adding roles in fosuserbundle sumfony2

Tags: fosuserbundle

I need to add new roles in fosuserbundles because I went to make differentiation between user:student or teacher and admin.

When I register roles as default as Role_user that's why i went to add student or teacher when i went to register and when i make this command in `cmd :php app/console fos:user:demote testuser ROLE_ADMIN php app/console fos:user:demote testuser ROLE_Student`.

It accept it so i went how i can add some roles when i register
Please can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The same way you demote a user, you can promote a user by calling:

```
php app/console fos:user:promote user role
```

You must have your role defined in the security.yml